# How to add event listeners to frame window using JavaScript?

Tags: html, frame, addeventlistener, keydown

I am trying to write a chrome extension for a website that is structured like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    ....
</head>
<frameset>
    <frame>
        ....
    </frame>
    <frameset>
        <frame>
            <html>
                <head>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <select id="theThingIWant"></select>
                </body>
            </html>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            ....
        </frame>
    </frameset>
</frameset>
</html>
```

I know that looks totally insane, but it was made a long time ago, and it's something I have to use at work.  I'm trying to access that `select` element, but the only way I've been able to do so is by adding a `click` listener to the `window` object that checks the `event.target` to make sure the `id` is what I'm looking for.

Ideally, I want to trigger a function after a `keydown` event where the `Tab` key has been pressed, then basically do the same thing, but I don't seem to be able to trigger the listener, no matter where I try and attach it.

My click event, which does what I want:

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.id === 'selAxisViaAEHybridContent')
        remove_content_IDs(e.target);
});
```

My keydown event, which does not work (the console logs never happen):

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {   
    console.log(e);
});
```

I can access the `frame` that the `select` element is in by using `document.getElementsByTagName('frameset')[1].children[0]`, but the `.children` property on that is an empty array.  When I attach the `keydown` event to that node, it still doesn't work.  Does anyone have any idea what I can do to solve this?  Ultimately, I want to run `remove_content_IDs()` when the `select` element is focused on via the `Tab` key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To bind `keydown` within the `iframe` use iframe's `contentWindow` property.

This might be helpful.

```
var ifr = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
var ifr_window = ifr.contentWindow;
ifr_window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    console.log("clicked ", e.keyCode);
});
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for.  You're a true gentleman.

Comment: Ohh! Thanks for the compliment. :)

Comment: I actually have a follow up question, as this only kind of solved my problem:

Each time I click a link in the frame, the DOM for that frame reloads, and it seems that whatever event listeners I created on that frame when the main window loaded are lost.  How can I prevent or get around this?

Comment: @EricDavidSartor can you add script in your frame src document?

Comment: I cannot unfortunately.  I'm not a dev, just someone trying to make their job easier...